# How to count if there's a cell with certain restrictions using Vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm finding if there at least one cell with the first character equal to "!"

Formula I have used without success:

```
=Vlookup("!";Left(N2:N49;1);1)
```

Why doesn't it work? And what do I have to change in the formula to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VLOOKUP function - Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

> Use VLOOKUP, one of the lookup and reference functions, when you need
>   to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up an
>   employee's last name by her employee number, or find her phone number
>   by looking up her last name (just like a telephone book).

You just need a count, not a lookup.

Use `COUNTIF` with a wildcard character.

```
=COUNTIF(N2:N49,"!*")
```

Or to make it a condition,

```
=COUNTIF(N2:N49,"!*")>0
```

Comment: Used it and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

1. I would add formula `=Left(N2,1)` to a new column, in this example
   **M**;
2. the formula can then be changed to `=Vlookup("!",M2:M49,1,False)`.